# Saving a list of indexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I normally save the selected indexPath of a `UiTableView` in `NSUserDefaults`, this is how I normally do it:

```
self.lastIndexPathUsed = indexPath.row;

NSUserDefaults *userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userdefaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row] forKey:@"lastIndexPathUsedForSellerType"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then I restore it:

```
    self.lastIndexPathUsed = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastIndexPathUsedForSellerType"] floatValue];
```

So `self.lastIndexPathUsed` is just a float value.

The above works fine on a single select table view. However on a multi-select tableview I can't see to get it working.

While the UITableView is on screen I save all the indexPaths into an array. However saving that array into `NSUserDefaults` causes a crash due to indexPath not being an object as such.

How to save an array how indexPaths into NSUserDefaults?

Comment: You save a value like a string, but you retrieve it like a float? This makes very little sense...

Comment: As much sense as storing an index as a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to archive your array to `NSData` before saving them to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSData *indexPathArrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_indexPathArray];
```

and after getting the `NSData` from `NSUserDefaults`, you can unarchive them :

```
_indexPathArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:indexPathArrayData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourMutableArray forKey:@"Key"];
```

And then get it like this :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"]];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since the array has indexPaths in it - you can't put it into NSUserDefaults like that. A crash happens.